# ec2 wait for instance to come up with timeout [Python]

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm using AWS python API (boto3).  My script starts a few instances and then waits for them to come up online, before proceeding doing stuff.  I want the wait to timeout after a predefined period, but I can't find any API for that in Python.  Any ideas?  A snippet of my current code:

```
def waitForInstance(id):
    runningWaiter = self.ec2c.get_waiter("instance_status_ok")
    runningWaiter.wait(InstanceIds = [id])
    instance = ec2resource.Instance(id)
    return instance.state
```

I can certainly do something like running this piece of code in a separate thread and terminate it if needed, but I was wondering whether there is already a built in API in boto3 for that and I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 1):

A waiter has a configuration associated with it which can be accessed (using your example above) as:

```
runningWaiter.config
```

One of the settings in this config is `max_attempts` which controls how many attempts will be tried before giving up.  The default value is 40.  You can change that value like this:

```
runningWaiter.config.max_attempts = 10
```

This isn't directly controlling a timeout as your question asked but will cause the waiter to give up earlier.

Comment: I'd rather access it programmatically.  I can't entirely predict where the script in question will run.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check the instances status from time to time?

```
#code copy from boto3 doc 
for status in ec2.meta.client.describe_instance_status()['InstanceStatuses']:
  print(status)
```

refence : http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/migrationec2.html

BTW, it is better to use tag naming for all the instances with a standard naming convention. Query any aws resources with its original ID is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Not a big problem in my case, because I start and stop instances automatically.  Once the task is done, the instance is terminated and gone for good

Answer (score 0):

You could put a sleep timer in your code.  Sleep for x minutes, check it to see if it is finished and go back to sleep if not.  After y number of attempts take some sort it action.

Comment: Well, this was another's guy's suggestion below